# How to restore /System/Library/Speech/Voices/ deleted folder MacOS

Tags: macos, text-to-speech, osx-yosemite, voice

I deleted **the whole** directory `/System/Library/Speech/Voices/` by mistake.

Stupid I know... How do I get it back with minimal damage? 
Is there somewhere the default voice file to download? 
There was an old post on MacRumors but the link is dead...

OSX = 10.10.5

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Download the Yosemite Installer (in AppStore.app > Purchased)
- Download [Pacifist](https://www.charlessoft.com)
- Open the Yosemite installer package with right-click > Show Package Contents
- Navigate to `./Contents/SharedSupport`
- Open OSInstall.mpkg with Pacifist
- The voices are in the packages

  - EssentialSystemSoftware > AdditionalSpeechVoices
  - EssentialSystemSoftware > EssentialSystemSoftwareGroup > BaseSystemResources
  - EssentialSystemSoftware > EssentialSystemSoftwareGroup > Essentials

Copy the files and make sure that you restore also the original access privileges `root:wheel 644`. This is crucial.

Comment: Worked! Also `install at default location` seems to have restored permissions